# Changing Value of adjacent column based on value of of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
    A1  A2  B1  B2
 0  10  20  20   NA
 1  20  40  30   No
 2  50  No  50   10
 3  40  NA  50   20
```

I want to change value in column A1 to NaN whenever corresponding value in column A2 is No or NA. Same for B1.
**Note**: NA here is a string objects not NaN.

```
     A1  A2  B1   B2
 0  10   20  NaN  NA
 1  20   40  NaN  No
 2  NaN  No  50   10
 3  NaN  NA  50   20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use if `NA` and `No` are strings use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or :

```
df.loc[df.A2.isin(['NA','No']), 'A1'] = np.nan
```

Or [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['A1'] = df['A1'].mask(df.A2.isin(['NA','No']))
```

---

If `NA` is missing value test it by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df.loc[df.A2.isna() | df.A2.eq('No'), 'A1'] = np.nan
```

Or:

```
df['A1'] = df['A1'].mask(df.A2.isna() | df.A2.eq('No'))
```